# parse error in running a exe GitHub action

Tags: windows, github-actions

So I'm trying to create a Github action workflow that uses signtool. (none of the marketplace actions work for me.. ). It looks like this https://github.com/AceCentre/RelayKeys/blob/7c1454c2b32b3e234c46444e6f090f391ea86d3b/.github/workflows/build.yml#L31

```
- name: Sign Windows Binary
  run:  |
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /a /td sha256 /fd sha256 /v /f "win-cert.p12" /p "${{ secrets.CERTPASSWD }}" /v "RelayKeys setup.exe"
```

But it fails. I get this parse error.

```
ParserError: D:\a\_temp\63b9a5c1-d675-443f-9f82-b82bac3b1007.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  … (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /a /td  …
     |                                                             ~~~~
     | Unexpected token 'sign' in expression or statement.
```

So what am I doing wrong? I've run other command line applications in the same way. Is it something to do with the slashes escaping things?

Answer (score 0):

Its because by default it runs powershell. If you see these kind of parse errors check if It will run locally in powershell.

You can change it by

```
& 'command..'
```

or tell the section to run with cmd

```
shell: cmd
```